# Using "UNION" with "IF EXISTS"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following problem on SQL Server 2008 R2, I'm trying to use an `IF EXISTS` clause on a group of `UNION` and I'm getting an error.

If I run the query separated, they run without errors, but if I try to run them with an UNION, it gave me the error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

```sql
SELECT
    '1.5.2- Customers' as INPUT,
    count (distinct ID) as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
FROM
    [BASE]
WHERE
    BASE.CAT_CUSTO = 'EMPLO' and
    BASE.ESTAT = 'EX'
group by
    PRO_DATE

UNION 

IF  EXISTS (
    SELECT
        '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
        count (distinct ID)  as Z,
        PRO_DATE,
        Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
        Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
    FROM
        [BASE]
    WHERE
        BASE.CAT_CUSTO <> 'EMPLO'
    group by
        PRO_DATE
)  begin
SELECT
        '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
        count (distinct ID)  as Z,
        PRO_DATE,
        Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
        Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
    FROM
        [BASE]
    WHERE
        BASE.CAT_CUSTO <> 'EMPLO'
    group by
        PRO_DATE

 end
ELSE
    SELECT TOP 1
        '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
        0 as Z,
        PRO_DATE,
        Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
        Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
    FROM
        [BASE]
```

Comment: You are confusing T-SQL control flow code and SQL queries.  Not an unusual confusion, but you would be better off describing what you want to do (i.e. sample data and desired results) rather than showing code that obviously cannot work.

Comment: `Top 1` without `order by` just picks a random record from the table.

Comment: @Magnus yeah that mystified me too.

Comment: the last part with the "top 1" is only to get just 1 record, since if i have 100, ill get 100 same results (results for every record on the table)

Comment: @ThatguyfromIT are you ok with getting a random `PRO_DATE`?

Comment: Thats just when the data process, and i get the month and year to filter on excel

Answer (score 2):

You say

```
q1

union 

if exists(q2)

  q3

else

  q4
```

does not work but all the queries work.  I doubt it looking at the queries but if this is the case then just change it to

```
if exists(q2)

  q1

  union 

  q3

else

  q1

  union 

  q4
```

Comment: nono, its like q1

union 

if exists(q2)

  q2

else

  q3

Comment: @ThatguyfromIT - ok... the fact that I called q2 q3 in the second reference DOES NOT MATTER to the logic of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table:

```
SELECT
    '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
    count (distinct ID)  as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
  INTO #temp
FROM
    [BASE]
WHERE
    BASE.CAT_CUSTO <> 'EMPLO'
group by
    PRO_DATE
```

and then

```
IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp > 0
BEGIN
SELECT
    '1.5.2- Customers' as INPUT,
    count (distinct ID) as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
FROM
    [BASE]
WHERE
    BASE.CAT_CUSTO = 'EMPLO' and
    BASE.ESTAT = 'EX'
group by
    PRO_DATE

UNION 

SELECT
    '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
    count (distinct ID)  as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
FROM
    [BASE]
WHERE
    BASE.CAT_CUSTO <> 'EMPLO'
group by
    PRO_DATE

 end

ELSE

SELECT
    '1.5.2- Customers' as INPUT,
    count (distinct ID) as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
FROM
    [BASE]
WHERE
    BASE.CAT_CUSTO = 'EMPLO' and
    BASE.ESTAT = 'EX'
group by
    PRO_DATE

UNION 

SELECT TOP 1
    '1.6- OTHER CUSTOMERS' as INPUT,
    0 as Z,
    PRO_DATE,
    Month(PRO_DATE) as P_MONTH,
    Year(PRO_DATE) as P_YEAR
FROM
    [BASE]
```

Comment: sounds nice, let me give it a try, since im looking to edit the ssis to do these steps separated

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @chk NVARCHAR(1)='B';
/** change @chk as 'C' to see the result**/
WITH T1 AS(SELECT * FROM(VALUES('A',1))a(F1,F2)
),T2 AS(SELECT * FROM(VALUES('B',2))a(F1,F2)
),T3 AS(SELECT * FROM(VALUES('C',3))a(F1,F2)
),CHK AS(SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE F1=@chk) THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END[chk_f]
) SELECT * FROM T1 UNION SELECT T2.* FROM T2,CHK WHERE chk_f='B' UNION SELECT T3.* FROM T3,CHK WHERE chk_f='C'
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes